# Character rendering Issues (characters aren't readable)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, motherboard, lenovo-laptop

A few weeks ago, I sent my laptop for repairs because it experienced a black screen with interesting-looking stripes at the bottom:

[image: blackscreen]

After receiving my laptop back, I was informed that the mainboard had been replaced. Now, I'm encountering a different issue. Sometimes characters won't render correctly or are unreadable, as shown in the example

[image: here]

[image: another one]

I initially suspected it might be my GPU driver. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it using various methods I'm familiar with. I've used DDU numerous times, deleted the driver in the device manager, and attempted different installation approaches, both with the driver provided by Lenovo specifically for my laptop and using the AMD tool.

Could this be a software problem, or is the hardware still faulty?
Laptop specs:

[image: here]

Comment: Given the nature of the repair, anything we might offer would be conjecture.   Ask the company that repaired the laptop,  use BIOS (UEFI) update on USB or CD and update BIOS, then if still issues back up and reinstall the OS

Comment: Since individual characters are unreadable, I assume the wrong font is being used for the system & desktop. See https://www.howtogeek.com/716407/how-to-change-the-default-system-font-on-windows-10/

Comment: I tried changing the default system fond but it only worked temporarly for the charackters only.
As for the BIOS Update, the company still hasnt replied since almost a week and I tried finding OS updates but couldnt find some working for my Laptop that can be used on a USB